# Matlab database prepared statements and bind variables

Tags: database, matlab, sql-injection

I'm rather new to Matlab, but I've had success using it to interact with a database (PostgreSQL in my case) by following the official documentation on how to [connect to a database using JDBC drivers](http://au.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/postgresql-jdbc-windows.html#bt8koan-3), and then [executing a query with `exec`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/exec.html#bt2rlcf-5). However, the example given in the latter case involves pasting data into the query, which can be inefficient and open to SQL injection.

What I'd really like to do is use bind variables, such as would be done in a [JDBC `PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). I can't find anything about this in the documentation. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do so, as you pointed, but you may also do all this by means of Matlab Database Toolbox.

### Data insertion via Matlab Database Toolbox

In fact, this toolbox works with PostgreSQL via a direct JDBC connection. Moreover, both implemented data insertion methods, `datainsert` and `fastinsert`, work via specially created prepared statements. The only difference between these two is in the way the respective prepared statements are filled with data. `fastinsert` does this in Matlab by using exactly the same technique you mentioned (by using different setters like `setDouble`, `setBoolean`, `setTimestamp` and so on as well as
certainly `setObject`). But it turns out that this way is difficult to use in case of big data volumes because in such cases `fastinsert` becomes very slow.
`datainsert` fills the created prepared statement with data within Java via a certain object of
`com.mathworks.toolbox.database.writeTheData` class. This class implements two methods―`doubleWrite` and `cellWrite`.
`doubleWrite` allows to fill the prepared statement with numerical scalar data. 
`cellWrite` assumes that data is passed as a cell matrix with a scalar object in each cell (with the object being either a numeric, a logical Matlab scalar, a Matlab string or a scalar Java object supported by JDBC driver, say, `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray` in the case of an array) for the
corresponding field and tuple. Thus, instead of calling `setObject` from Matlab (this may lead to 
a significant overhead) it is more efficient to fill the mentioned cell matrix with necessary objects as the first step
and then call `datainsert` from Matlab Database Toolbox as the second step.

### Performance of data insertion methods

But in the case all the objects being inserted have Matlab types 
(scalars, strings, matrices, multi-dimensional arrays, structures and arbitrary other Matlab types),
there is at least one more efficient way to insert data using a special high-performance PostgreSQL
client library written 100% in C and basing on libpq. It is called [PgMex](https://pgmex.alliedtesting.com).
It is especially useful for big data volumes (about 1Gb and more) or when it is
necessary to insert non-scalar data (arrays). In such cases both `fastinsert` and `datainsert` demonstrate a degrading performance and a constant lack of Java heap memory caused by limitations of JDBC driver for large data set. This can be easily
seen from the following pictures:

[image: The case of scalar numeric data]
[image: The case of arrays]

Here the performance of `fastinsert` and `datainsert` is compared with the one of `batchParamExec`
from PgMex (see https://pgmex.alliedtesting.com/#batchparamexec for details). The first picture is for the case of scalar numeric data, the second picture is for arrays. Endpoint of each graph corresponds
to a certain maximum data volume passed into the database by the corresponding method without any error.
A data volume greater than that maximum (specific for each method) causes “out of Java heap memory” problem
(Java heap size for each experiment is specified at the top of each figure).
For further details of experiments please see the following
[paper with full benchmarking results for data insertion](https://alliedtesting.github.io/pgmex-blog/2017/06/29/performance-comparison-of-postgresql-connectors-in-matlab-part-I/).

EDIT: Now [PgMex](http://pgmex.alliedtesting.com/) supports free academic licenses.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I've managed to answer my own question, so I'm sharing the love. AFAICS the database toolbox is very basic, but fortunately one can use Java's JDBC API directly, as I spied in the support team response to [this question](http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97768-how-do-i-insert-an-image-or-figure-into-a-database-using-the-database-toolbox-in-matlab).

So prepared statements can use bind variables like so:

```
% Assume schema
% CREATE TABLE (idcol SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, colX INTEGER, colY INTEGER);

    jdbcconn = conn.Handle
        stmt = jdbcconn.prepareStatement(['INSERT INTO mytable ('...
            'colX, colY) '...
            'VALUES (?,?) '...
            'RETURNING idcol']);
    stmt.setObject(1, x);    
    stmt.setObject(2, y);    
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    success = rs.next();
    newentry_id = getInt(1);
    close(rs);
    close(stmt);
```

Comment: You should mark this as correct when the required time has lapsed.

Comment: @Dan thanks, will try to remember in 2 days time... Hope you found it useful.